# RESTful POST issue (GWT): application/x-www-form-urlencoded instead of application/xml

Tags: xml, rest, gwt, post, jetty

I am writting a GWT client.
I need to send a post request to call a REST service on my server.

```
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.POST, url);
builder.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
builder.setHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
```

I send some serialized data to XML format but on the server side it receives

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

**Service on server side**

```
@POST
@Path("/connexion")
@Consumes("application/xml")
@Produces("application/xml")
public Response test(A a){
// ...
}
```

i don't understand what is happenning.
Thx

Comment: Related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3190927/775715

Comment: I already have something similar to the related code. With firebug, I checked the content-type : it is set to application/xml, but on my server it has changed. My POJO is well serialized (XML) and attached to the request body. I still have the error.